# cross compile freetype for android

Tags: android-ndk, cross-compiling, freetype

i am trying to use free type in android native and i am trying to follow this tutorial: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Android#FreeType which seems to be the standard tutorial that everyone links to.

my problem now is that i have never cross compiled anything before and when i try to prepare the cross-compiler with: make-standalone-toolchain.sh ... in cygwin (im on windows 7) i get:

```
-bash: make-standalone-toolchain.sh: command not found
```

even though it definitely is there. what am i missing? or is that not to be done in cygwin at all but somewhere else? this standard tutorial is not detailed enough for me, can anyone give me a more detailed explanation on where i have to give those commands?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to compile and use freetype 2.7.1 library in ndk with CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# freetype 2.7.1
add_definitions(-DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY)

set(FTDIR "src/main/cpp/freetype")
include_directories(${FTDIR}/include)

set(FTSRC
  ${FTDIR}/src/autofit/autofit.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftbase.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftbbox.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftbdf.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftbitmap.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftcid.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftfntfmt.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftfstype.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftgasp.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftglyph.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftgxval.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftinit.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftlcdfil.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftmm.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftotval.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftpatent.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftpfr.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftstroke.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftsynth.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftsystem.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/fttype1.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftwinfnt.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/bdf/bdf.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/bzip2/ftbzip2.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/cache/ftcache.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/cff/cff.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/cid/type1cid.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/gzip/ftgzip.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/lzw/ftlzw.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/pcf/pcf.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/pfr/pfr.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/psaux/psaux.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/pshinter/pshinter.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/psnames/psnames.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/raster/raster.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/sfnt/sfnt.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/smooth/smooth.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/truetype/truetype.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/type1/type1.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/type42/type42.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/winfonts/winfnt.c
  ${FTDIR}/src/base/ftdebug.c
  ${FTDIR}/include/ft2build.h
  ${FTDIR}/include/freetype/config/ftconfig.h
  ${FTDIR}/include/freetype/config/ftheader.h
  ${FTDIR}/include/freetype/config/ftmodule.h
  ${FTDIR}/include/freetype/config/ftoption.h
  ${FTDIR}/include/freetype/config/ftstdlib.h
)

add_library( freetype SHARED ${FTSRC} )
```

and then you link it to your ndk library : e.g.

```
add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(native-lib freetype)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't just run .sh script in windows environment... You have to use sh.exe utility to strat your script... somethiong like:

```
path_to_cygwin\bin\sh make-standalone-toolchain.sh [options]
```

Answer (score 0):

on macos platform:

build64

```
#!/bin/bash

export NDK= /Users/xxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147 # set your path
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
SYSROOT=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot


export API=21
export TARGET=aarch64-linux-android
CPU=arm64-v8a

export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang
# old
#export CFLAGS="-g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fPIC  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=$TOOLCHAIN "
# with -g
export CFLAGS="-g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fPIC  --target=$TARGET$API --gcc-toolchain=$TOOLCHAIN "
# without -g
#export CFLAGS="-DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fPIC  --target=$TARGET$API --gcc-toolchain=$TOOLCHAIN "
export AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ar
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ranlib


PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU

function build
{
./configure \
--host=$TARGET \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--without-brotli \
--with-zlib=no \
--with-bzip2=no \
--with-png=no \
--with-harfbuzz=no \
--with-sysroot=$SYSROOT \

make -j12 VERBOSE=1
make install
}

build
```

build32

```
     #!/bin/bash

export NDK=/Users/xxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147 # set your path
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
SYSROOT=$TOOLCHAIN/sysroot


export API=21
export TARGET=armv7a-linux-androideabi
CPU=armeabi-v7a

export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang
# old
#export CFLAGS="-g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fPIC  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --gcc-toolchain=$TOOLCHAIN "
# with -g
export CFLAGS="-g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fPIC  --target=$TARGET$API --gcc-toolchain=$TOOLCHAIN "
# without -g
#export CFLAGS="-DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -fPIC  --target=$TARGET$API --gcc-toolchain=$TOOLCHAIN "
export AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ar
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ranlib


PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU

function build
{
./configure \
--host=$TARGET \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--without-brotli \
--with-zlib=no \
--with-bzip2=no \
--with-png=no \
--with-harfbuzz=no \
--with-sysroot=$SYSROOT \

make -j12 VERBOSE=1
make install
}

build
```